# Physical meaning of the Morse functions?

Tags: string-theory, differential-geometry, supersymmetry, topology

What is the physical correspondence of the Morse functions in a physical system? Currently I am studying Mirror symmetry but I can not get a physical intuition out of it.

Comment: Comments to the post (v3): 1. Consider adding context and references in order to receive focused and useful answers. 2. That said, the [Morse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) is typically a [superpotential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpotential).

Comment: What do you mean by "the" Morse functions? A Morse function is *any* function that has only isolated critical points (and almost all functions are Morse functions - the set of Morse functions is dense in the $C^2$ functions).

Comment: Thank you both I am a new member and i will ask a better question next time. @ACuriousMind i think you are right it is general not specific.